# Determine the function of $f(z)$: singularities and residue

Tags: taylor-expansion

Can anybody help me by explaining step by step how to solve this question?

The function $f(z)$ has a double pole at $z=0$ with residue $2$ and a simple pole at $z=1$ also with residue $2$. It is also analytic at all other finite points of the plane and is bounded as $|z| \to \infty$. Also $f(2)=5$ and $f(-1)=2$. Determine $f(z)$.

- The answer is $f(z) = (z^3+3z^2+2z-4)/(z-1)z^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Two singularity $0$ and $1$. Moreover $0$ is a pole of order $2$ and $1$ a simple pole. Therefore $$f(z)=\frac{G(z)}{z^2(z-1)}$$
with $G$ holomorphe. Now $$\frac{G(z)}{z^2(z-1)}=\frac{-G(0)}{z^2}+\frac{2}{z}+...$$
and $$\frac{G(z)}{z^2(z-1)}=\frac{2}{z-1}+...=\frac{G(1)}{z-1}+...$$

I let you conclude...

Comment: I'm sorry, Surb. I kind of new toward this chapter. I really don't understand. :)